# change text in table cell using rowIndex and cellIndex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got index of a row. Column count is static so I know in which column to put what, but what I want is to be able using onclick event handler to change content in the specific cell. the element which has this onclick event applied is outside the table with all the text inputs that I want to copy contents from. a brief example

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td>SomeText</td>
<td>SomeOtherText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SomeText2</td>
<td>SomeOtherText2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="box1">
<form>
<input type="text" name="newText"/>
<input type="button" onclick="?" />       
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to this specific cell using something like:

```
$('#table1 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')
```

Here it will select second row's second column (it's 0 based counting).

And then you can use `jQuery.text()` or `jQuery.html()`.

You may do something like the following:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td>SomeText</td>
<td>SomeOtherText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SomeText2</td>
<td>SomeOtherText2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then in you onclick method you can do something like following:

```
$('#table1 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').text("Whatever text you want");
```

OR

```
$('#table1 tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').html("Whatever text you want");
```

Comment: Thanks. Hope it also works for the person who has asked this.

Comment: "tr:eq()" - can I put javascript variable inside? I'm not sure it's working

Comment: `var yourVariable=1;
$('#table1 tr:eq(' + yourVariable + ') td:eq(1)').text("Whatever text you want");`

Comment: You just need to create the selector string, so you can just split the string and insert in between as you would do with any other string expressions in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the java script and id.

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td id=r1c1>SomeText</td>
<td id=r1c2>SomeOtherText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id=r2c1>SomeText2</td>
<td id=r2c2>SomeOtherText2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>

function updatetxt(){
x=Document.getElementById(r1c1);
x.value=Document.getElementById(txt1).value
    }    
</script>
    <div id="box1">
    <form>
    <input type="text" id=txt1 name="newText" />
    <input type="button" onclick="updatetxt()" />       
    </form>
    </div>
```